# Is there any alternative for WebJobs in AWS (like in Azure)?

Tags: azure, amazon-web-services, azure-webjobs

I need to implement scheduled tasks, so that every X time the job will start running and will start an .exe file.

I did this those tasks in Azure very easily, but can't find something appropriate in Amazon Web Services.

Can you tell me if there is something similar in AWS for Azure WebJobs?

Comment: You now also have Azure Functions, which are basically the same as WebJobs, but they do not require a WebSite to run on. They're documented here: https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/services/functions/ You just can't beat Azure :)

Comment: I have not used it but do check out AWS Lambda - http://docs.aws.amazon.com/lambda/latest/dg/welcome.html.

Comment: @GauravMantri AWS Lambda would probably work but this involves code which I would like to avoid.
WebJobs does not contain any code for what I want to do.

Comment: then there's no other alternatives as Azure WebJobs in AWS - Lamba (for now) is the AWS proposed solution

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The most similar piece of AWS services that fits your needs is AWS Lambda. But as your comment states you do not want to code.

When comparing AWS to other cloud services it pops out that AWS focus on a very primitive services that can be connect and build complex systems. This is an advantage as one can tailor the cloud to its needs. However it can be more complex to setup when compared to a PaaS.